# Titanium Mobile local notifications at a certain time

Tags: ios, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I have been trying to setup local notifications with Titanium mobile for iOS, using a custom date time, but its not working with custom date time. What I am trying is

```
var notification = Ti.App.iOS.scheduleLocalNotification({
alertBody:"Dummy text",
alertAction:"Re-Launch!",
userInfo:{"hello":"world"},
date: new Date("2015-03-22 01:45")
});
```

However when I use this for date, It works.

```
date: new Date(new Date.getTime()+8000)//Current date time + 8 secs after.
```

What should I do to make this work.

```
date: new Date("2015-03-22 01:45")
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The date string you are passing to the constructor is not valid.
You could use something like:

```
date: new Date("1/20/2015 00:00:00")
```

Where the format is MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS